# Как в webpack 4 <link> добавлять в <body>, а не <head>

Tags: webpack

Вот так выглядит мой `webpack.config.js`, я хочу, чтобы один файл стилей был в `<head>`, а второй файл подключался в теге `<link>` внизу `<body>`

Я думал, можно это сделать с помощью `style-ext-html-webpack-plugin-webpack-4` плагина, но, он не работает, по идее, при установки `position` можно выставить куда переписать `<link>`, однако, это не работает, файл из файловой системы пропадает (как будто подключился) но в файле html не появляется `<style>` с содержимым, наверное ошибка самого плагина.

Если у меня где-то ошибка, прошу, подскажите! Или если и правда дело в плагине, подскажите, как можно другим способом добиться такого же результата. Спасибо!

```js
const
    styles            = require('./webpack/styles'),
    scripts           = require('./webpack/scripts'),
    img               = require('./webpack/img'),
    fonts             = require('./webpack/fonts'),
    path              = require('path'),
    Html              = require('html-webpack-plugin'),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin"),
    Imagemin          = require('imagemin-webpack-plugin').default,
    StyleExtHtml      = require('style-ext-html-webpack-plugin-webpack-4'),
    Clean             = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = (env, options) => {
    const isDevMode = options.mode === "development";
    const dist = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');
    const src = path.join(__dirname, 'src');

    return {
        context: src,
        entry: {
            main: './index.tsx',
            head: './styles/style-for-head.styl',
        },
        output: {
            path: dist,
            filename: 'js/[name].js',
        },
        devtool: isDevMode && 'source-map',
        devServer: {
            overlay: true,
            // host: '192.168.1.71',
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
        },
        plugins: [
            new Html({
                template: 'index.html'
            }),
            new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name].css'),
            

            // Вот подключение этого плагина
            new StyleExtHtml({
                file: 'css/head.css',
                // position: 'body-bottom' // файл стилей удалится из системы, но в html так и не появится его содержимое
            }),


            new Clean([dist]),
            new Imagemin({
                test: /\.(png|gif|jpe?g|svg)$/i
            }),
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                styles(isDevMode),
                scripts(),
                img(),
                fonts()
            ],
        },

    }
};
```

Comment: в `html-webpack-plugin` есть параметр `inject`, если задать `new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './index.html', inject: 'body' })` - то всю статику плагин инжектит в бади, а не в хед

Comment: К, сожалению, inject: 'body' перемещает только подключение скриптов. Но, даже, если бы он перемещал и link, то, скорее всего, перенес бы и тот link, который я хочу оставить в head

Comment: здесь не в этом дело, какой смысл от `extract-text-webpack-plugin` - если вы все равно хотите инжектить стили после загрузки ДОМа, если использовать обычный `style-loader + css-loader`, то стили стрингифаятся в js файле и инжектятся в хед как инлайновые в теге `style`

Comment: Я понял, изменю текст. Я хочу в head чтобы стили были в style, а внизу body в link

Comment: как вы собираетесь поместить link в body? `This element defines a link. It may only appear in the HEAD section of a document, although it may appear any number of times.`

Comment: link можно помещать в body. То что я хочу - рекомендация google speed.
стили, необходимые для отображения главного экрана подключаются в head, в style, для улучшения загрузки, остальные стили подключаются перед скриптами.
Таким образом загружаются стили главного экрана, затем весь html, затем все остальные стили и уже потом скрипты. Такой порядок подключения положительно влияет на ранжирование сайта в результатах поиска

Comment: открыл google speed recommendations: `Все CSS-файлы необходимо размещать как можно выше в HTML-документе, чтобы браузер мог быстрее обнаружить тег и скачать файлы.`